# Add active class and bind window

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Hello everybody I have a html code, css, using blazor where I need to do some things in javascript.

my code:

```
.mywin {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}

.ItemActive {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: red;
}

.navigation.active {
    width: 50px;
}

.windowHome .windowInfo {
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

<div classe="mywin">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="ItemActive">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home icon"/><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell icon"/><span>Info</span>  </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="windowHome">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="windowInfo">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
@code {
    
}
```

1- Change the class `navigation` to `navigation active` by clicking on the button and when clicking again, go back to `navigation`

2 - Change the `ItemActive` class by clicking on another item, in this case I have two, `Home` and `Info`

3 - Display the window as I click on the Home and Info items, with `windowHome` for the `Home` item and `windowInfo` for the `info` item

Could someone show me how I can do this?

Comment: The only things you "need to do" in Javascript are probably handling media: playing and stopping multiple audio sources, etc.  I strongly recommend you going through a Blazor tutorial series on YouTube, as this kind of question will most certainly (like, 100% chance) be answered.

Comment: What do you mean `Change the ItemActive class by clicking on another item, in this case I have two, Home and Info`?You want change the class to which class?

Answer (score 0):

Something to start with using Blazor:

```
<div class="navigation @(@IsClicked ? "active" : "")">@(@IsClicked ? "active" : "")</div>
<ul>
    <li class="@(@IsClicked ? "" : "ItemActive")">
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home icon" /><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="@(@IsClicked ? "ItemActive" : "")">
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell icon" /><span>Info</span>  </a>
    </li>
</ul>

@if (@IsClicked)
{
    <div class="windowHome">
        windowHome
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="windowInfo">
        windowInfo
    </div>
}
@code {

    private bool IsClicked;

    protected void OnClick()
    {
        IsClicked = !IsClicked;
    }
}
```